# 3D Trigonometry Orientation

Tags: lua, trigonometry

I have a vector in a 3D view, defined by a point p1(x1, y1, z1) and a rotation r1(x1, y1, z1). I can get a direction and a yaw. I need that vector to point another point p2 (x2, y2, z2). So I need a new rotation.

[image]

Any tip or trick?

Comment: this is simple maths. how is this related to programming?  just subtract pos2 from pos1. this is not trigonemetry btw, this is linear algebra. as the name indicates trigonometry is about triangles, you just have two points

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about math and not really about programmin

Comment: Rotation matrix is implemented differently in different Lua APIs. What game engine your Lua script is designed for?